# Multiple Datasources to perform read and write separately

Tags: java, spring, jboss, datasource, jndi

In a spring java project i am having one datasource configured in `persistence-config.xml` as

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.company.common.persister.CompanyRoutingDataSource">
    <property name="targetDataSources">
        <map key-type="java.lang.String">
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="defaultDataSource" />
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="defaultDataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/CompanyXADS"/>
```

and in `standalone.xml` i have

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/CompanyXADS" pool-name="CompanyXADS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
```

If add another datasource i want to separate out the database calls to perform read for one database and write for database. `Spring` and `Hibernate` i am using only xml based not annotations i my project. Can anyone suggest how to implement without much code change.